# Symfony2 change default path where twig templates are created

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

While creating controllers from the console by typing `php app/console generate:controller` a few questions are asked, `controller name:` `routing format`, `template format`, and then the thing i'm intrested in `template name`

Here the option shows `AppBundle:admin:admin.html.twig` and the template is create inside the `AppBundle/Resources/views`.What i want is to have the template automatically created under `app/Resources/views folder` *through the command line prompt* i want the `template name` option to show `admin/admin.html.twig` instead

edit: and also the change from `{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}` to `{% extends "base.html.twig" %}`

any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you can't change directory destination of template with this command, path of template relate to the bundle.

You can easily use the command then doing change you want. If you have to do this often, maybe you create your own command extending the symfony's command.

Comment: could you possibly point me to any good documentation to create such a command? perhaps maybe a demonstration? documentation would be enough though